# Probabilities and Analysis

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm struggling in discovering the relationships between probabilities and when to use the appropriate rule, (multiplication, addition, join probability, etc.)

Given:

```
P(A) = 0.25
P(B) = 0.30
P(C) = 0.55
P(A and C) = 0.05
P(B and C) = 0
P(B|A) = 0.48
```

How do I go about finding:

1. If A and B are independent events?
2. P(A and B)
3. P(A or B)
4. P(A|B)
5. Are B and C mutually exclusive events?
6. Are B and C independent events? How do I prove this?

Comment: ... one question at a time?

Comment: and check the definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1$. $A$ and $B$ are not independent, since $P(B|A)=0.48\neq0.30=P(B)$

$2$. By the definition of conditional probability $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)=0.25\cdot0.48=0.12$

$3.$ $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=0.25+0.30-0.12=0.43$

$4.$ $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)=0.12/0.30=0.40$

$5.$ $B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive, since $P(B\cap C)= 0$

$6.$ $B$ and $C$ are not independent, since $P(B\cap C)=0\neq0.30\cdot 0.55=P(B)P(C)$